# Empty camera names in Flash Player with Google Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, camera

So, it seems we got another problem with devices (cameras and microphones) in Flash Player integrated with Google Chrome (PPAPI). Many Flash developers can remember [clickjacking problem](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Spycam-vulnerability-reappears-in-Google-Chrome-s-Flash-1892051.html) and ugly fix for this issue implemented in Google Chrome. For now, if you have some application that uses camera or microphone, Google Chrome users must allow access to their devices twice: for Flash Player (small window centered in Flash-object) and for Google Chrome (gray panel with buttons under address bar).

Until recently the whole process of granting camera access looked like this:

1. Application want to attach camera to Video object or NetStream.
2. Even without permission you can get camera names and populate some
   UI components with them.
3. Flash Player show security panel with "Allow" and "Deny" buttons.
4. Google Chrome show it's own security panel, so both security panels
   are visible at the same time.
5. Users press "Allow" button in Flash Player security panel.
6. Now you have false for camera.muted property, but camera show zero
   FPS, because access is still denied in browser.
7. Users press "Allow" button in browser security panel.
8. Win! You have access granted everywhere.

Of course, that second security panel of Google Chrome is a real pain. Users just don't notice it. Flash developers handled this issue with hints inside application and FAQ pages. But now we have another big problem.

Recently the process of granting camera access changed to this:
Application want to attach camera to Video object or NetStream.

1. You can't get camera names until access granted in browser. There
   will be just spaces (" ", symbol with code 32) in camera.name
   property.
2. Flash Player show security panel with "Allow" and "Deny" buttons.
3. Google Chrome will not show it's security panel until access granted
   in Flash Player.
4. Users press "Allow" button in Flash Player security panel.
5. Now you have false for camera.muted property, but camera show zero
   FPS and have no name, because access is still denied in browser.
6. Google Chrome show it's own security panel.
7. Users press "Allow" button in browser security panel (this panel
   shown twice for some reason).
8. Now you have access granted everywhere, but devices still have just
   spaces instead of real names.

Unfortunately, AS3 will not update camera names after access granted in browser. Camera names are empty event in Flash Player settings window before browser access granting. So it's impossible now to get camera names in Flash application running in Google Chrome without reloading. User need to grant access in browser first, than reload application and only after that we can get camera names in AS3. I have tried to use flash.media.scanHardware() to refresh camera names, but it seems it's not working.
Also I have created a small example and posted it online: http://wonderfl.net/c/rcIh

You can test it by yourself in Google Chrome. Just don't forget to clear your choice each time. You need to remove "wonderfl.net" entry from list on *chrome://settings/contentExceptions#media-stream* to clear your prevoius choice.
Also I got similar complaints from Opera users.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.media.scanHardware;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class BrowserPermissionTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var output:TextField;
        private var timer:Timer;

        public function BrowserPermissionTest()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            output = new TextField();
            output.border = true;
            output.multiline = true;
            output.wordWrap = true;
            output.x = output.y = 10;
            addChild(output);

            updateView();
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stage_resizeHandler);

            var i:int;
            var numCameras:int = 0;
            var numMicrophones:int = 0;

            if (Camera.isSupported)
            {
                var cameraNames:Array = Camera.names;
                numCameras = cameraNames ? cameraNames.length : 0;
                if (numCameras > 0)
                {
                    log("Cameras:");
                    for (i = 0; i < numCameras; i++)
                    {
                        var cameraName:String = cameraNames[i];
                        log((i + 1) + ". \"" + cameraName + "\"");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    log("Camera not found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                log("Camera is not supported.");
            }

            log("");

            if (Microphone.isSupported)
            {
                var microphoneNames:Array = Microphone.names;
                numMicrophones = microphoneNames ? microphoneNames.length : 0;
                if (numMicrophones > 0)
                {
                    log("Microphones:");
                    for (i = 0; i < numMicrophones; i++)
                    {
                        var microphoneName:String = microphoneNames[i];
                        log((i + 1) + ". \"" + microphoneName + "\"");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    log("Microphone not found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                log("Microphone is not supported.");
            }

            log("");

            if (numCameras > 0 || numMicrophones > 0)
            {
                if (numCameras > 0)
                {
                    var defaultCamera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
                    var video:Video = new Video(1, 1);
                    addChild(video);
                    video.attachCamera(defaultCamera);
                    defaultCamera.muted ? devicesMutedInFlashPlayer() : devicesUnmutedInFlashPlayer();
                }
                else if (numMicrophones > 0)
                {
                    var defaultMicrophone:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
                    defaultMicrophone.setLoopBack(true);
                    defaultMicrophone.muted ? devicesMutedInFlashPlayer() : devicesUnmutedInFlashPlayer();
                }
                else
                {
                    log("No devices found for test.");
                }               
            }
        }

        private function devicesMutedInFlashPlayer():void
        {
            log("Devices are muted in Flash Player.");
            log("Starting permission check timer...");

            timer = new Timer(100);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flashPlayerPermissionTimer_timerHandler);
            timer.start();
        }

        private function flashPlayerPermissionTimer_timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            var defaultCamera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
            if (!isDevicesMutedInFlashPlayer())
            {
                timer.stop();
                timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, flashPlayerPermissionTimer_timerHandler);
                timer = null;

                devicesUnmutedInFlashPlayer();
            }
        }

        private function devicesUnmutedInFlashPlayer():void
        {
            log("Devices are unmuted in Flash Player.");
            isDevicesMutedInBrowser() ? devicesMutedInBrowser() : devicesUnmutedInBrowser();
        }

        private function devicesMutedInBrowser():void
        {
            log("Devices are muted in browser.");
            log("Starting permission check timer...");

            timer = new Timer(100);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, browserPermissionTimer_timerHandler);
            timer.start();
        }

        private function browserPermissionTimer_timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            scanHardware();
            if (!isDevicesMutedInBrowser())
            {
                timer.stop();
                timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, browserPermissionTimer_timerHandler);
                timer = null;

                devicesUnmutedInBrowser();
            }
        }

        private function devicesUnmutedInBrowser():void
        {
            log("Devices are unmuted in browser.");
        }

        private function isDevicesMutedInFlashPlayer():Boolean
        {
            var cameraNames:Array = Camera.names;
            var numCameras:int = cameraNames ? cameraNames.length : 0;
            if (numCameras > 0)
            {
                var defaultCamera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
                return defaultCamera.muted;
            }
            else
            {
                var microphoneNames:Array = Camera.names;
                var numMicrophones:int = microphoneNames ? microphoneNames.length : 0;
                if (numMicrophones > 0)
                {
                    var defaultMicrophone:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
                    return defaultMicrophone.muted;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private function isDevicesMutedInBrowser():Boolean
        {
            var cameraNames:Array = Camera.names;
            var numCameras:int = cameraNames.length;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < numCameras; i++)
            {
                var cameraName:String = cameraNames[i];
                if (cameraName != " ")
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            var microphoneNames:Array = Microphone.names;
            var numMicrophones:int = microphoneNames.length;
            for (i = 0; i < numMicrophones; i++)
            {
                var microphoneName:String = microphoneNames[i];
                if (microphoneName != " ")
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private function log(text:String):void
        {
            output.appendText(text + "\n");
        }

        private function updateView():void
        {
            output.width = stage.stageWidth - 2 * output.x;
            output.height = stage.stageHeight - 2 * output.y;
        }

        private function stage_resizeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            updateView();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I wonder if it's a bug or some kind of new security feature implemented by Google Chrome team? Maybe someone already faced this problem and can share more info about it.
For now it looks like modern browsers killing Flash with all that features and ugly solutions.

PS: You can find some silly mistakes in my message. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I havent checked your code but just saying.. Google or Chrome never got it right with a customised Flash Player. Just use the official Adobe plugin where possible and advise the same. Even simple things like text (especially encoding for foreign characters is almost unusable) yet the official plugin worked perfectly..

Comment: To avoid reloading for camera names.. (if PPAPI == true) then you could make your app not check for any camera names until a specific function runs. Then only run that function when user confirms in your U.I that they granted browser access (if they lie and just click okay then too bad they have to reload) otherwise now its safe for your app to check.

Comment: Thanks VC.One. Unfortunately, I can't force users to use official Flash Player, because it's very difficult for many of them to dig into chrome://plugins. Also there is no way to force Chrome to use NPAPI Flash instead of PPAPI Flash. It would be a security issue because of PPAPI sandboxing. As for primary browser access check... You see, the problem is most users will just leave the site after one or two minor problems and this thing with browser is a problem.

Comment: But the whole idea about browser is good. Maybe it's possible to call getUserMedia in JavaScript first, than wait for user choice and only after that check cameras inside Flash.

Comment: After couple of tests I have found strange behavior of PPAPI Flash.
The test was made with two SWFs working simultaneously on the same page. The first one was asking for device access like some regular application (by calling video.attachCamera). The second SWF was created/removed in cycle by JavaScript to avoid this thing (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()): "Scanning the hardware for cameras takes time. When the runtime finds at least one camera, the hardware is not scanned again for the lifetime of the player instance."

Comment: I have made both SWFs to get all devices names and post them to screen. So I was able to see all changes regarding devices in first SWF (before and after permission granted) and in refreshable second SWF (each second). Also I have used scanHardware in both SWfs.
I have found that second (refreshable) SWF got correct list of devices, but first one got only microphones. Camera names was empty.
So it looks like we have another bug of PPAPI Flash here. I don't have another explanation for this. I mean, why do they need to update only microphones, but not cameras?